# Commerce Kickstart and product variations

Tags: commerce

I am relatively new to Drupal and I am trying to build an eShop with Drupal Commerce Kickstart.

One of the good features is the ability to have product variations and attributes in variation type which affect the price of the product.

Unfortunately, I have not managed to make it work correctly.

My main issue is that the "All Products" page show only main products and not the variations and that on this page the facets of the attributes that are in variation type are not show-up. They work only the facets that are for the attributes of the content type of the product.

If I do not find a solution soon, I will forced to give up these two very powerful features of Drupal Commerce and simply have products without variations.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: This is due to how Commerce Kickstart is configured for entering new products. You enter product variations while adding the product.

When you create a *product* in Commerce Kickstart, you're actually creating the node that the customer will see. Scrolling down the page, you'll see the ability to add the individual *product variations* (which are the actual product entities) like so:

[image: showing the inline entity form on the "drinks" product add page]

This is an [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) (aka IEF). See, normally when you'd use Drupal Commerce, you'd need to create all of your individual entities and then add them to a product using a product relationship field. But this a Drupal [field widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vph6KmebCxI) take takes that step out by letting you enter in your product data and relate it to the display node in one step.

If you want to see all of the product variations, there should be a tab at the top of the Products admin page that will take you to a listing:

[image: Tabs at the top of the admin products listing page]

You can edit products here, but you can't add them directly because of how Kickstart controls the product add process.

Comment: Dear @nvahalik thank you for your reply.
I want the user (customer) of the web site (eShop) to see all the variations in the "All Product" page and use the facets in order to find what he wants...
The admin can see all the variations there but this is not the issue here...
Thank you again for your great reply :)

Comment: @agorts, then you probably want to not use Commerce Kickstart and instead switch to "vanilla" Drupal Commerce. You can still add in a lot of the nice functionality that Kickstart has, but it sounds like your use case deviates from what CK is useful for.

Comment: My use case is an ordinary eshop which try to use the product variations...
I found hard to believe that the variations does not working in Drupal Commerce Kickstart.
It must be a solution out there...